# C++ address value and sizeof

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

On my computer. When I test the code:

```
int main()
{
    int i=123;
    return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test
```

I found when I enter:

```
print &i            output: 0x7fffffffe18c
print sizeof(&i)    output: 8
```

I was confused, the address of i is 6 byte, why `sizeof(&i)==8`?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What  the address is the evidence of 6 bytes? ex) when output: 0x0.1 Byte?

Comment: _"... when I enter ..."_ Where did you enter wut please?

Comment: How about `sizeof(1)`, do you think it should be `1`?

Comment: Because the full address is `0x00007fffffffe18c` including leading zeros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do this, you are getting the address of i

```
print &i            output: 0x7fffffffe18c
```

The output show the address number that the variable i is stored, but printf will remove the leading zero, so you could only see **0x7fffffffe18c** instead of **0x00007fffffffe18c**, you could use a debugger to verify it

When you call sizeof(&i)

```
print sizeof(&i)    output: 8
```

You getting 8 bytes, because you are getting the sizeof the address and not the variable i size, if you want to get the variable size just do

```
sizeof(i)
```

Comment: @green2rabbit if you want to see the leading zero, use a debugger and stop at the &i, you could see those leading zeroes or you could format your printf to include the leading zeros

Answer (score 3):

The address is actually `0x00007fffffffe18c`, print doesn't display the leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` works with types, not values, because values must ultimately be stored in a container of some type, and the compiler usually can't predict what value a variable is going to have to hold at compile time:

```
void f(int* ptr);  // does it need to hold 0? 1000? 1<<27?
```

When you write

```
sizeof(i);
size_t f(int* ptr) { return sizeof(ptr); }
```

is actually treated as equivalent to

```
sizeof decltype(i);
size_t f(int* ptr) { return sizeof(decltype(ptr)); }
```

where `decltype(i)` evaluates to whatever type `i` was declared as:

```
int i; :- decltype(i) evaluates to "int"
int* i; :- decltype(i) evaluates to "int*"
int*& i; :- decltype(i) evaluates to "int*&"
```

and in `f`

```
sizeof(ptr) :- decltype(ptr) evaluates to "int*"
```

You compiled a 64-bit executable so pointers have to be able to hold values [0,1^64), which requires 64-bits or 8 bytes.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    printf("i = %d, &i = %0p, sizeof(&i) = %d\n", i, &i, sizeof(&i));
}
```

On a 32-bit machine: http://ideone.com/htfy9R